# Gunicorn and Django error permission denied for sock

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Trying to setup a site with django and gunicorn getting this error in the nginx log file:

```
2017/01/31 07:04:50 [crit] 30386#30386: *1 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 197.232.12.165, server: kenyabuzz.nation.news, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock:/", host: "kenyabuzz.nation.news"
```

static files are served correctly. The gunicorn file in nginx/sites-enabled settings

```
#kb gunicorn nginx settings

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name kenyabuzz.nation.news;

    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/static/kb/favicon.ico; # favicon
    }


    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock;
    }
}
```

and the gunicorn setting `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 10 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

checked the status of gunicorn

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-133:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-01-31 06:59:49 UTC; 8min ago
 Main PID: 30281 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jan 31 06:59:48 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jan 31 06:59:49 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, sta
Jan 31 06:59:49 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 31 06:59:49 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have your gunicorn process running as user Ubuntu and Group www-data

```
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
```

Typically in ubuntu, nginx runs as www-data. I See that you have defined www-data as the group for gunicorn. Therefore you can solve this problem by

```
chmod g+x /home/ubuntu/
chmod g+r /home/ubuntu/
```

Assuming that you have www-data as the group for the above folder. If not you can change it with

```
sudo chgrp www-data /home/ubuntu/
```

Comment: Tried this got a file doesn't exist so I uploaded a file with the same name to the folder applied permissions to the folder checked the logs (still getting a 502) permission denied `2017/01/31 08:10:57 [crit] 31000#31000: *13 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 197.232.12.165, server: kenyabuzz.nation.news, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock:/", host: "kenyabuzz.nation.news"`

Comment: you can't simplhy place a file there!! That's a socket created by gunicorn when it starts. If there isn't a file there that means gunicorn isn't running. Remove your dummy file and start gunicorn again and see if the file exists.

Comment: updated the details, the file isn't created, included gunicorn status log also.

Comment: created a related question @e4c5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955530/gunicorn-django-sock-file-not-created

Comment: great will look