# Gunicorn & django sock file not created

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Setting up django with nginx and gunicorn I've been able to have it serve static files but brings a 502 on django. The site runs okay with `runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` I've also worked on uwsgi before, I don't think the two (gunicorn and uwsgi) are conflicting however.

When I run gunicorn status check I get

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-133:~$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-01-31 10:36:23 UTC; 4min 20s ago
  Process: 32261 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 10 --bind unix:/home/ubu
 Main PID: 32261 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jan 31 10:36:23 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jan 31 10:36:23 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, 
Jan 31 10:36:23 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 31 10:36:23 ip-172-31-16-133 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

and the error log reads

```
2017/01/31 10:36:31 [crit] 32205#32205: *7 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 105.231.127.174, server: kenyabuzz.nation.news, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "kenyabuzz.nation.news"
```

Here's the conf file

```
#kb gunicorn nginx settings

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name kenyabuzz.nation.news;

    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/static/kb/favicon.ico; # favicon
    }


    #location / {
    #    include proxy_params;
    #    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock;
    #}

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;

            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}

upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Gunicorn service settings

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 10 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**UPDATE**

Running gunicorn using `gunicorn kb.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001` returns

```
WSGI without exception
```

kb.wsgi file doesn't exist also this may be the issue

Comment: it's here that your gunicorn config should be posted. Please also try starting gunicorn manually without using systemd

Comment: can you share the command to run

Comment: The answer you have recieved shows how to run it (leave out the ExcecStart= part) Update question with errors you have got

Comment: /home/ubuntu/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 10 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application

Comment: kb.wsgi notation means a file called wsgi in a folder called kb. Of course you should be in the top level folder for your project when you run this command. And you should use the exact same full path for gunicorn as in your systemd (because there maybe another installation of gunicorn on your system)

Comment: I'm running it from the main directory of the django site I got that was assuming it might be related to the issue

Answer (score 4):

It seems like a problem on your /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service ExecStart command, try runing the same command from the command line to troubleshoot it.

ExecStart example:

```
ExecStart=/home/user/Virtualenvs/app_virtualenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/local/django/app.sock app.wsgi:application
```

You may need to set also the User, Group and WorkingDirectory for the service:

```
[Service]
User=yourAppUser
Group=yourAppGroup
WorkingDirectory=YourAppWD(where manage.py is located)
ExecStart=...
```

Comment: There should be a file called wsgi.py inside your app dir (kb) try runing this from the directory where the manage.py is located `gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:kb.sock kb.wsgi:application`

Comment: you should get an output like this: `$ gunicorn cpc.wsgi:application --bind unix:kb.sock`
`[2017-01-31 14:34:38 +0000] [5842] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0`
`[2017-01-31 14:34:38 +0000] [5842] [INFO] Listening at: unix:kb.sock (5842)`
`[2017-01-31 14:34:38 +0000] [5842] [INFO] Using worker: sync`
`[2017-01-31 14:34:38 +0000] [5847] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5847`