# Django app not being served via nginx on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-22.04

I have attempted twice to deploy a django app on ubuntu 22.04 and serve it using nginx but it doesn't work. The [guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html) I am using has worked on previous versions of ubuntu.

Upon completion of the guide, I get an 502 gateway error. While inspecting the log errors, I get this error.

```
4286#4286: using inherited sockets from "6;7;"
```

The closest I have come to answer is this [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427115/nginx-shows-502-bad-gateway-error-after-upgrade-to-lts-22-04-1) but the developer is working with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was an issue with permissions.

Inspecting logs from nginx-error.logs, I got

```
connect() to unix:/path/to/gunicorn.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41952296/5895888) worked for me.